# the property name of label.xalign property is not xalign. xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have added **Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView** package to my project. I am getting an exception "**the property name of label.xalign property is not xalign.**" I have all the Xamarin.Forms package version above 2.3 , Kindly give me some inputs.
Below is the xaml:

```
<Label TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" MinimumWidthRequest="60"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding .ProjectDisplayId}"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML

Comment: Please check the edited question

Comment: there is not xaml

Comment: xamarin forms deprecated XAlign and replaced it with HorizontalTextAlignment in labels. Might be they did something similar to carouselview? I'd try looking for that. Also, your xaml isn't in the question I think you pasted it wrong.

Comment: edited the question again.. yah i have replaced it with horizontalTextAlignment but its effecting other UI

Comment: Then you need to fix your UI with `HorizontalTextAlignment` in place, because like @Slepz mentioned; `XAlign` is deprecated and will not work anymore.